# Speeding up creating a view

Tags: mysql

Can anyone suggest anyways to speed up this view I've created?
It gets the correct data from the database but the compilation is so slow because its doing so many selects, but I'm not sure how to combat that.

Here is the query:

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `ResponseMonthly_View`
AS SELECT 
(SELECT SurveyMonth
    FROM surveyResponse_View AS v
    WHERE v.SurveyMonth = main.SurveyMonth GROUP BY v.SurveyMonth) AS SurveyMonth,
(SELECT Count(*)
    FROM surveyResponse_View AS v
    WHERE v.SurveyMonth = main.SurveyMonth GROUP BY v.SurveyMonth) AS Responses,
(SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM surveyResponse_View AS v
    WHERE v.funded = 1 AND v.SurveyMonth = main.SurveyMonth GROUP BY v.SurveyMonth) AS FundedResponses,
(SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM surveyResponse_View AS t
    WHERE t.funded = 0 AND t.SurveyMonth = main.SurveyMonth GROUP BY t.SurveyMonth) AS UnfundedResponses,

(SELECT ROUND(AVG(NoOfUL))
    FROM surveyResponse_View AS m
    WHERE m.SurveyMonth = main.SurveyMonth AND NoOFUl < 200 AND TutorSession < 200 AND IndependentSession < 200 AND DedicatedSession < 200  GROUP BY m.SurveyMonth) AS AllNoOfUl,

(SELECT ROUND(AVG(TutorSession))
    FROM surveyResponse_View AS m
    WHERE m.SurveyMonth = main.SurveyMonth AND NoOFUl < 200 AND TutorSession < 200 AND IndependentSession < 200 AND DedicatedSession < 200 GROUP BY m.SurveyMonth) AS AllTutorSession,

(SELECT ROUND(AVG(IndependentSession))
    FROM surveyResponse_View AS m
    WHERE m.SurveyMonth = main.SurveyMonth AND NoOFUl < 200 AND TutorSession < 200 AND IndependentSession < 200 AND DedicatedSession < 200 GROUP BY m.SurveyMonth) AS AllIndependentSession,

(SELECT ROUND(AVG(DedicatedSession))
    FROM surveyResponse_View AS m
    WHERE m.SurveyMonth = main.SurveyMonth AND NoOFUl < 200 AND TutorSession < 200 AND IndependentSession < 200 AND DedicatedSession < 200 GROUP BY m.SurveyMonth) AS AllDedicatedSession,

(SELECT ROUND(AVG(TutorSession) + AVG(IndependentSession) + AVG(DedicatedSession) / Count(*))
    FROM surveyResponse_View AS m
    WHERE m.SurveyMonth = main.SurveyMonth AND NoOFUl < 200 AND TutorSession < 200 AND IndependentSession < 200 AND DedicatedSession < 200 GROUP BY m.SurveyMonth) AS AverageForSum,

(SELECT ROUND(AVG(NoOfUL))
    FROM surveyResponse_View AS m
    WHERE m.SurveyMonth = main.SurveyMonth AND funded = 1 AND NoOFUl < 200 AND TutorSession < 200 AND IndependentSession < 200 AND DedicatedSession < 200  GROUP BY m.SurveyMonth) AS FundedNoOfUl,

(SELECT ROUND(AVG(TutorSession))
    FROM surveyResponse_View AS m
    WHERE m.SurveyMonth = main.SurveyMonth AND funded = 1 AND NoOFUl < 200 AND TutorSession < 200 AND IndependentSession < 200 AND DedicatedSession < 200 GROUP BY m.SurveyMonth) AS FundedTutorSession,

(SELECT ROUND(AVG(IndependentSession))
    FROM surveyResponse_View AS m
    WHERE m.SurveyMonth = main.SurveyMonth AND funded = 1 AND NoOFUl < 200 AND TutorSession < 200 AND IndependentSession < 200 AND DedicatedSession < 200 GROUP BY m.SurveyMonth) AS FundedIndependentSession,

(SELECT ROUND(AVG(DedicatedSession))
    FROM surveyResponse_View AS m
    WHERE m.SurveyMonth = main.SurveyMonth AND funded = 1 AND NoOFUl < 200 AND TutorSession < 200 AND IndependentSession < 200 AND DedicatedSession < 200 GROUP BY m.SurveyMonth) AS FundedDedicatedSession,

(SELECT ROUND(AVG(TutorSession) + AVG(IndependentSession) + AVG(DedicatedSession) / Count(*))
    FROM surveyResponse_View AS m
    WHERE m.SurveyMonth = main.SurveyMonth AND funded = 1 AND NoOFUl < 200 AND TutorSession < 200 AND IndependentSession < 200 AND DedicatedSession < 200 GROUP BY m.SurveyMonth) AS FundedAverageForSum,

(SELECT ROUND(AVG(NoOfUL))
    FROM surveyResponse_View AS m
    WHERE m.SurveyMonth = main.SurveyMonth AND funded = 0 AND NoOFUl < 200 AND TutorSession < 200 AND IndependentSession < 200 AND DedicatedSession < 200  GROUP BY m.SurveyMonth) AS UnfundedNoOfUl,

(SELECT ROUND(AVG(TutorSession))
    FROM surveyResponse_View AS m
    WHERE m.SurveyMonth = main.SurveyMonth AND funded = 0 AND NoOFUl < 200 AND TutorSession < 200 AND IndependentSession < 200 AND DedicatedSession < 200 GROUP BY m.SurveyMonth) AS UnfundedTutorSession,

(SELECT ROUND(AVG(IndependentSession))
    FROM surveyResponse_View AS m
    WHERE m.SurveyMonth = main.SurveyMonth AND funded = 0 AND NoOFUl < 200 AND TutorSession < 200 AND IndependentSession < 200 AND DedicatedSession < 200 GROUP BY m.SurveyMonth) AS UnfundedIndependentSession,

(SELECT ROUND(AVG(DedicatedSession))
    FROM surveyResponse_View AS m
    WHERE m.SurveyMonth = main.SurveyMonth AND funded = 0 AND NoOFUl < 200 AND TutorSession < 200 AND IndependentSession < 200 AND DedicatedSession < 200 GROUP BY m.SurveyMonth) AS UnfundedDedicatedSession,

(SELECT ROUND(AVG(TutorSession) + AVG(IndependentSession) + AVG(DedicatedSession) / Count(*))
    FROM surveyResponse_View AS m
    WHERE m.SurveyMonth = main.SurveyMonth AND funded = 0 AND NoOFUl < 200 AND TutorSession < 200 AND IndependentSession < 200 AND DedicatedSession < 200 GROUP BY m.SurveyMonth) AS UnfundedAverageForSum



FROM surveyResponse_View AS main WHERE NoOFUl < 200 AND TutorSession < 200 AND IndependentSession < 200 AND DedicatedSession < 200 GROUP BY SurveyMonth;
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Change the query. You don't need so many subselects. Use conditions summing/avg...

Comment: You can group by multiple values. `GROUP BY t.SurveyMonth, t.funded` etc.

Comment: @juergend Could you give an example? I'm really new to sql

Comment: somethig like `select avg(case when col1= 'a' and colb = 2 then col_to_avg else 0 end) ...`